# Como parar uma Thread?

Tags: java

Como eu faço para parar uma thread em execução com comandos do Java?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Thread.stop()

Existe o método `Thread.stop()` que tem esta finalidade. No entanto ele está obsoleto (*deprecated*). Ele ainda funciona se for utilizado, mas existem fortes razões para você não utilizá-lo.

Quando uma thread é interrompida de forma súbita, ela pode deixar operações importantes inacabadas. Por exemplo, imagine que ela estivesse salvando informações em um arquivo e ao ser interrompida de forma súbita o arquivo acaba corrompido. Ou suponha que ela estivesse fazendo alguma operação crítica com algum objeto na memória e ao ser interrompida de forma súbita, este objeto acaba ficando em um estado inconsistente e corrompido? Esta é a razão pela qual o `Thread.stop()` foi descontinuado.

O `Thread.stop()` funciona ao lançar de forma súbita um `ThreadDeath` dentro da thread que foi parada a força. Isso significa que a thread ainda terá os blocos `finally` executados, e se ela der um `catch (ThreadDeath e)` ou um `catch (Throwable e)`, ela poderá capturar o `ThreadDeath` e acabar por não ser parada. Isso pode parecer ser bom, mas se o `ThreadDeath` for lançado de dentro de um bloco `finally`, o `finally` acaba sendo interrompido deixando alguma coisa muito importante inacabada. Se você tentar tratar isso ao capturar o `ThreadDeath`, um outro `Thread.stop()` pode causar um novo `ThreadDeath` dentro do código que deveria estar tratando o `ThreadDeath`, e por causa disso, na prática é impossível tratar o `ThreadDeath` de forma adequada.

Para piorar, vamos supor que a thread estava dentro de um código pertencente a alguma biblioteca que estava fazendo uma operação qualquer com arrays, enfim, algo que não tenha nada a ver com o `Thread.stop()` ou com o `ThreadDeath`. Você até tem um `catch (ThreadDeath e)` em algum lugar fora da biblioteca em um método que você a usa. Quando o `ThreadDeath` for capturado, o código da biblioteca executou apenas pela metade deixando um monte de coisas inconsistentes. E aí, como é que você conserta essas coisas? Como é que você sequer descobre o que ficou inconsistente?

## Thread.stop(Throwable), Thread.suspend() e Thread.destroy()

Além do `Thread.stop()` há uma variante `Thread.stop(Throwable)` (também obsoleta) que para a thread com uma exceção arbitrária, ao invés de um `ThreadDeath`. Isso é ainda pior porque você continua com o mesmo problema do `Thread.stop()`, mas agora ao invés de um `ThreadDeath` você tem uma exceção qualquer e portanto fica mais difícil escrever código que possa tratar isso. Em versões mais modernas da JDK, este método apenas lança um `UnsupportedOperationException`, sendo este um dos pouquíssimos casos onde houve uma quebra de retrocompatibilidade proposital no Java.

Existe o método `Thread.suspend()` que para a thread e deixa que ela possa continuar depois com `Thread.resume()`. No entanto, este método também pode acabar deixando operações importantes incompletas e objetos inconsistentes devido a súbita interrupção da thread. Além disso, ele pode resultar em *deadlocks*, uma vez que quaisquer *locks* sobre objetos (aqueles que são obtidos em blocos e métodos `synchronized`) continuam travados para a thread em suspensão. Por este motivo, estes métodos também estão obsoletos.

Existe também o método `Thread.destroy()` (obsoleto) que deveria parar a thread imediatamente e destruí-la. Este método nunca foi implementado e tentar utilizá-lo resulta em uma exceção. Se tivesse sido implementado, o resultado seria semelhante a um `Thread.suspend()` onde não há a opção de se fazer um `Thread.resume()`.

## Interrompendo threads de forma graciosa

Para parar uma thread de forma graciosa, ela deve estar executando código que prevê a sua interrupção de forma graciosa. Isso pode ser simplesmente codificar a thread de forma a verificar de vez em quando se uma variável `boolean` ou `AtomicBoolean` ou alguma condição especial a fim de determinar se a thread deve parar ou não. Ou seja, o código da thread é projetado para saber quando ele deve ser interrompido e voluntariamente fazer isso de forma graciosa.

## Thread.interrupt()

A forma recomendada de interromper threads é com o método `Thread.interrupt()`. Este método não interrompe a thread de fato, apenas seta uma flag nela (o status de interrupção). Você pode saber se a thread atual foi interrompida pelo uso dos métodos `Thread.interrupted()` e `Thread.isInterrupted()`. Estes métodos retornam um `boolean` dizendo se a thread foi interrompida ou não. A diferença entre eles é que o `Thread.interrupted()` limpa o status de interrupção (o define como `false`), enquanto que o `Thread.isInterrupted()` não o altera. Além disso, o `Thread.interrupted()` é um método estático que verifica e limpa o estado de interrupção da thread que o invocou (`Thread.currentThread()`), enquanto que o `Thread.isInterrupted()` é um método de instância da classe `Thread`.

Vários métodos da JDK (ex: `Thread.sleep` e `Object.wait`) lançam a exceção `InterruptedException`. Esta exceção é lançada quando a thread que está executando estes métodos (`Thread.sleep`, `Object.wait` ou outros) é interrompida pelo uso do `Thread.interrupt()`. Desta forma, é possível interromper uma thread que esteja presa em um `Thread.sleep` ou `Object.wait`. É importante que a thread interrompida trate a `InterruptedException` de forma satisfatória (simplesmente capturá-la e ignorá-la sem pensar direito no que está se fazendo, não é uma boa prática de programação). Quando a `InterruptedException` é lançada, o status de interrupção da thread é limpo (setada para `false`), uma vez que quando a exceção estiver sendo capturada, a interrupção já estará sendo tratada.

Se você for projetar um método que pode ficar preso por muito tempo, uma boa alternativa é verificar o `Thread.isInterrupted()` ou o `Thread.interrupted()` e lançar o `InterruptedException`. Por exemplo:

```java
public void metodoDemorado() throws InterruptedException {
    while (/*alguma coisa*/) {
        // faz qualquer coisa
        if (Thread.interrupted()) throw new InterruptedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ainda vou abrir uma discussão no meta pra encontrarmos uma tradução melhor pra *deprecated*. "Depreciado" quer dizer outra coisa :)

Comment: @bfavaretto Sempre chamei de "obsoleto"...

Comment: @mgibsonbr Eu também, mas como verbo não funciona (precisa dizer "tornar obsoleto"). E talvez exista um termo que transmita melhor o sentido. Em português até existe "deprecar", mas é jargão jurídico usado de maneira um pouco diferente (apesar de haver semelhanças semânticas com o termo inglês).

Comment: @bfavaretto "Descontinuado" então? Tipo "o suporte ao método X foi descontinuado". Essa [*"Portuguese Language"*](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/64172/portuguese-language?referrer=MkJ531PqRl8UwGHuhaux3w2) está fazendo falta... :P

Comment: @bfavaretto abre lá no PL ;)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Agradeço a edição. Só peço para que tome um pouco mais de cuidado com o gênero (obsolet**a** vs obsolet**o**).

Comment: Para mim soava melhor da primeira forma, mas posso estar enganado.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento O método fica obsolet**o**, e não obsolet**a**. Porque **método** é um substantivo masculino. :)