# Controle de Threads em Java

Tags: java, thread, multithreading

Tenho um sistema multi thread em Java que utiliza a classe `ThreadGroup` que está deprecated.

Com a minha implementação atual também não consigo "matar" uma thread em lock. Como implementar um código eficiente para controle de `Thread` em Java?

Preciso ter ao mínimo controle sobre o tempo de execução, inicialização e finalização do meu `Pool` de Threads.

Código simplificado do que preciso fazer de uma forma mais eficiente:

```
int threadAtivas = 5;
ThreadGroup threadGroup = new ThreadGroup("threads");
while(true){
    if(verificaQtdThreadsAtivas(threadGroup)){
        criaNovaThread(threadGroup);
    }else{
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/45320/132

Comment: Você pode dar mais detalhes explicando melhor de que consiste esse pool? Como ele é instanciao e como você o utiliza?

Comment: Melhorei a pergunta com um código exemplo.

Comment: O seu exemplo de código não está bom, afinal a variável `threadGroup` não está sendo usada em lugar nenhum, então a sugestão mais simples, mas que provavelmente não serve para nada na prática, seria simplesmentte remover a segunda linha disso. Além disso o `Thread.sleep(1000)` lança um `InterruptedException`. Esta exceção é fundamental para responder a sua pergunta, e portanto, como você a está tratando?

Comment: Completei o exemplo. Não estou tratando a `InterruptedException`, como devo tratar?

Answer (score 1):

Use o `ExecutorService`, ele é uma classe para pool de threads. Você instancia dizendo quantas threads vão rodar simultaneamente, daí vai adicionando teus `Runnable` nele e espera terminar.

```java
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class SimpleThreadPool {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Runnable worker = new WorkerThread("" + i);
            executor.execute(worker);
          }
        executor.shutdown();
        while (!executor.isTerminated()) {
          // fica aqui enquanto está rodando as threads
        }
        System.out.println("Finished all threads");
    }

}
```

Comment: O metodo shutdown() irá setar uma flag para interromper as threads em andamento.

Comment: Não vai interromper as threads, **SEM** o `shutdown` ele ficar esperando você mandar mais `Runnable` pro `ExecutorService` (fica com o pool em memória), **COM** o `shutdown` ele não vai aceitar a adição de mais nenhum `Runnable` e conforme as threads forem finalizando ele vai tirando da memória o espaço de pool alocado.

Comment: Sem o `shutdown` suas threads continuaram na memoria parada; 
Porem ao sairem do estado `runnable` irão liberar o pool do `ExecutorService`,  sobre isso não existe duvida, mas se voce chamar o shutdown antes do fim da execucao de uma thread, não irá setar uma flag em todas threads para interrompelas?