# O que é IPC (Inter Process Communication)?

Tags: terminologia, multithreading, processo

Numa discussão com experientes programadores aqui do site a respeito de [controle de concorrência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/211394/o-que-%C3%A9-controle-de-concorr%C3%AAncia), surgiram os termos [semáforos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/211354/), *mutex*, *memória compartilhada*, [monitor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/208859/4995), e ainda outros, os quais estou começando a entender agora.

Toda essas minhas dúvidas começaram quando perguntei sobre [processos assíncronos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/207775/4995), onde percebi que eu não estava entendendo muito bem sobre o termo *assíncrono* e acabei aprendendo sobre [bifurcação de processos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/210285/4995).

No meio disso tudo, comecei a pesquisar muitas coisas a respeito de processos de sistemas operacionais. E foi aí que aprendi mais um termo: *IPC* — que disseram que significa *inter process communication*.

Mas o que é IPC mais detalhadamente?

De que forma ele se relaciona com os termos que eu citei acima, sobre os quais disse que eu estava discutindo?

Comment: Talvez seja o caso de você consolidar um pouco mais o que sabe antes de formular as perguntas... Porque tenho a impressão de que as respostas vão ter muita sobreposição. A propósito, acho que cabe a tag [tag:multithreading] nessas perguntas todas.

Comment: @bfavaretto pensa num cara que dessa vez realmente não sabe nada sobre o assunto? Sou eu. A maioria das vezes que pergunto no site, é porque já sei a resposta, mas dessa vez foi diferente. Peço desculpas se acabei formulando alguma coisa de maneira ruim, mas é que não vi nada no site falando diretamente sobre o assunto.

Comment: @bfavaretto eu tava querendo até perguntar o que era System V, porque nunca tinha ouvido falar disso antes.

Comment: Não é que as perguntas estão mal formuladas, é que você está encavalando um monte de pergunta relacionada. Talvez desse pra fundir algumas delas. Mas também não sou especialista na área, pode ser que não dê. A minha dica é só pra segurar um pouco o ritmo ;)

Comment: @bfavaretto se for o caso, podemos fechar as perguntas. Eu não me importo com isso. Eu geralmente realmente gosto de separar cada termo em uma pergunta. Mas talvez possamos pelo menos marcar como duplicada, para ter mais referências.

Comment: @bfavaretto realmente estou "cavalgando". Estou correndo pra lá e pra cá igual doido pra saber o que está por trás daquela pergunta que fiz sobre [msg_ em php](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/211357/qual-%C3%A9-o-objetivo-dessas-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-prefixadas-por-msg-em-php). Não quero tentar implementar nada sem saber direitinho se o que estou pensando sobre as funções está certo.

Comment: IPC seria a [Comunicação entre processos] (https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comunica%C3%A7%C3%A3o_entre_processos)

Comment: Por curiosidade, o que você está tentando implementar? Como eu disse, não entendo muito do assunto, mas pensaria duas vezes antes de lidar com múltiplas threads ou processos com PHP. Não parece a linguagem adequada para isso.

Comment: @bfavaretto concordo com você. PHP na verdade tem várias limitações quando a controle de processos (quando se usa Apache principalmente). A ideia mesmo era compreender como funciona aqueles *message queues* nativos do php que mostrei na outra pergunta, e como isso se relaciona com os termos : System V, IPC, shared memory, semaforos e afins...

Comment: Encontrei esse [link](http://www.ece.eng.wayne.edu/~gchen/ece5650/lecture5.pdf). Vou dar uma olhadinha depois.

Comment: Como usar IPC de forma errada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/45330/64969

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Sistemas operacionais multiprocessados são sistemas operacionais que são capazes de executar mais de um processo de uma vez. Exemplos são os sistemas UNIX, Windows da versão 95 em diante, e MacOS *Classic* (MacOS X também é multiprocessado, mas está incluído sob a rubrica UNIX já citada).

Uma característica muito importante dos sistemas multiprocessados é que eles implementam os chamados *espaços de endereços virtuais*, em que cada processo que executa enxerga a si próprio como se fosse o único processo executando na memória. Isso facilita muito o desenvolvimento dos programas, porque o programador não precisa se preocupar em acidentalmente ler, sobrescrever ou até executar dados ou código de um outro processo sem relação consigo, mas que calhe de estar rodando ao mesmo tempo.

Então o SO se preocupa em montar essa ficção de que cada processo é o único executando na máquina, e os processos simplesmente executam como se fossem os únicos no mundo. Isso funciona muito bem para programas simples, mas eventualmente um processo vai precisar se comunicar com outro — por exemplo, um programa gráfico vai querer se comunicar com o X/Wayland num ambiente UNIX. Como fazer neste caso?

Aí entram os mecanismos chamados de Comunicação Interprocesso (IPC, na sigla em inglês). Como os processos não podem conversar entre si acessando a memória um do outro, eles precisam de algum tipo de mecanismo — e existem vários — para conversar entre si quando isso for necessário. E como quem implementa essa separação entre os processos é o SO, então é responsabilidade do SO implementar esses mecanismos também.

O mecanismo mais simples de IPC é simplesmente o uso de arquivos. Isso era usado na época dos compiladores C antigos, em que o preprocessador pegava o código fonte e escrevia um arquivo com esse código preprocessado, e então o compilador pegava esse código e escrevia um programa *assembly* correspondente, o montador pegava o programa *assembly* e emitia o código objeto, e finalmente o *link-editor* juntava os códigos objeto e gerava o executável.

Um refinamento disso é o conceito de *pipe*, que é um arquivo que só existe enquanto os programas enquanto os programas em cada lado do *pipe* executam e só é visível para eles; outro maior são as soquetes de domínio UNIX (*UNIX Domain Sockets*), usadas pelo Wayland para fazer IPC; o uso de soquetes TCP/IP, COM, DCOM, CORBA, mapeamento de memória, mensagens Win32, são numerosos outros.

Um dos mecanismos de comunicação interprocesso é realmente estabelecer uma área de memória que os dois (ou mais) processos comunicantes conseguem acessar ao mesmo tempo, o que é simples e eficiente, mas pode causar problemas se mais de um processo tentar escrever a mesma região ao mesmo tempo. Neste caso, é preciso estabelecer algum tipo de protocolo para definir quem pode escrever onde e quando. Este protocolo são os semáforos, *mutexes* e aliados.

Em resumo, o conceito de IPC é um conceito que surge naturalmente a partir do conceito de isolamento de processos. Os métodos de se concretizar esse conceito são inúmeros; cada um tem características, vantagens e desvantagens próprias. Qual é mais apropriada para o seu caso específico depende de você.

Answer (score 23):

IPC: *inter process communication*. A parte mais fácil da pergunta já foi respondida, mas ela abrange muito mais por baixo.

Vou tomar a liberdade aqui e falar que processo é tudo aquilo que ocupa o processador para simplificar o entendimento, ok?

Os níveis de IPC variam de acordo com a tecnologia usada e a técnica para se fazer a comunicação. Vamos discutir um sistema computacional MIMD/processador com escalonamento de processos, do nível que eu considero mais desacoplado até o que eu considero mais acoplado.

Como estamos falando de múltiplos processos falando entre si, esses múltiplos processos não necessariamente precisam estar na mesma máquina. Vamos começar pelo caso de que eles estão na mesma máquina.

### Interfaces de comunicação

> Resumo:
>   Plexidade? Uniplex, half-duplex ou full duplex
>   Tipo de dado? Generalizado
>   Ativo/passivo? Ativo
>   Duração: Arbitrário/lifetime

São interfaces fornecidas pelo próprio sistema operacional. Podem ser *uniplex*, *half duplex* e *full duplex*. O exemplo mais típico de uma comunicação por interface *uniplex* é o *pipeline*, mais brevemente conhecido por *pipe*, ou até mesmo por `|` para os íntimos. Como isso funciona?

Tome um exemplo básico de shell script:

```
echo "furiosas ideias verdes dormem furiosamente" | sed -e 's/(^| )[aeiou][^ ]* /  /g' |
    sed 's/  */ /g' | tr -d aeiou
```

Aqui, cada processo funciona de modo suficientemente separado um do outro. Não há compartilhamento de memória, nem um processo sabe da existência um do outro. Por baixo, o bash está imprimindo a frase de efeito, então alimentando o primeiro `sed` (que remove palavras começadas por vogais, deixando um espaço no lugar), que então alimenta o segundo `sed` (que remove excesso de espaços) que, só então, lança para o `tr` deletar as vogais da entrada. A saída desse script é:

> `frss vrds drmm frsmnt`

#### Passo a passo do exemplo

`echo "furiosas ideias verdes dormem furiosamente"`

Entrada:

> 

Saída:

> `furiosas ideias verdes dormem furiosamente`

`sed 's/[aeiou][^ ]* / /g'`

Entrada:

> `furiosas ideias verdes dormem furiosamente`

Saída:

> `furiosas  verdes dormem furiosamente`

`sed 's/  */ /g'`

Entrada:

> `furiosas  verdes dormem furiosamente`

Saída:

> `furiosas verdes dormem furiosamente`

`tr -d aeiou`

Entrada:

> `furiosas verdes dormem furiosamente`

Saída:

> `frss vrds drmm frsmnt`

#### Outras comunicações interprocesso por interfaces

Foi apresentado já o *pipe*. Esse *pipe* também é conhecido como ***pipe* anônimo**, pois ele não foi nomeado. Também existe o *pipe* nomeado. Em sistema Unix, você cria um *pipe* nomeado através do comando `mkfifo`, então você põe um processo para escrever no *pipe* e outro para ler dele, como se fosse um arquivo do sistema de arquivos tradicional.

Outro modelo também é o *socket*. Um programa abre um *socket* e entra em modo de escuta, então outro programa se conecta e os dois passam a se falar pelo *socket*.

### MPI

> Resumo:
>   Plexidade? Full duplex
>   Tipo de dado? Generalizado
>   Ativo/passivo? Ativo
>   Duração: Arbitrário/lifetime

MPI é uma espécie de interface de comunicação, mas aqui há uma coesão maior, há um acoplamento mais intenso. Também pode-se dizer que isso aqui é multi computador, mas funciona muito bem com um computador só.

Imagine que você precisa saber como uma molécula se estrutura dado o pH e a temperatura do sangue humano (resquícios [da época](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43108223/4438007) em que trabalhava no [CENAPAD-UFC](http://www.cenapad.ufc.br/quem-somos/recursos/)). Essa molécula é grande demais, com partes quase independentes entre si, então você pode computar separadamente o comportamento de suas estruturas, chegar numa posição de estabilidade eletro-quântica e, então, atualizar a informação obtida pelo outro processamento para refinar seu posicionamento.

Essa troca de valores comumente se faz através de um envio de mensagens em um processamento tipo [BSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulk_synchronous_parallel).

> **BSP em quinze segundos**: grandes pedaços de processamento independentes que de quando em quando são sincronizados e trocam informação entre si.
>   Exemplo do BSP [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/214190/64969), através dos processos nas redes de ordenação.

### Memória compartilhada

> Resumo:
>   Plexidade? Full duplex
>   Tipo de dado? Generalizado
>   Ativo/passivo? Passivo
>   Duração: Arbitrário

Aqui dois ou mais processos compartilham parte da memória do computador. Eles escrevem na área comum, eles leem da área comum, mas também tem sua área privada. MPI pode ser montado em cima disso.

Normalmente é nesse nível que o programador começa a se preocupar com semáforos/mutex/monitores propriamente ditos. Antes, ele simplesmente sabe que essas coisas existem.

Esse compartilhamento de dados permite maior agilidade na execução, porém também é preciso mais controle do programador. Diferente de comunicação por interface, isso aqui não permite lançar um evento para que o outro processo tome uma ação: aqui, a comunicação é totalmente **passiva**.

Eu não preciso nem devo falar para o outro processo: olhe, dados! O outro processo simplesmente pega os dados.

### Variáveis compartilhadas

> Resumo:
>   Plexidade? Full duplex
>   Tipo de dado? Generalizado
>   Ativo/passivo? Passivo
>   Duração: Lifetime

Ok, alguns iriam argumentar que isso é um tipo de Memória Compartilhada, outros iriam argumentar que eu estou inventando esse nome. E, de fato, não lembro qual o nome correto, mas esse nome vem bem a calhar.

Aqui, não só há um espaço de memória compartilhado entre diversos processos, como de fato *toda* a memória é compartilhada. A partilha é tão grande que até pelos mesmos nomes as variáveis atendem. Esse é o modelo de IPC em *threads*.

### Envio de sinais

> Resumo:
>   Plexidade? Uniplex
>   Tipo de dado? Sinal/byte
>   Ativo/passivo? Ativo
>   Duração: Momento

Quem nunca recebeu um `SIGSEGV` quando programou em C?

`SIGSEGV` também é conhecido por *segmentation fault*, ou falha de segmentação. Esse é um [sinal Unix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal) enviado pelo sistema operacional falando que você acessou uma área de memória fora do esperado (acabou por violar o segmento de memória do programa).

Tem outros sinais muito característicos que usamos:

- sinal de pausa (CTRL+Z no terminal; `SIGSTOP`)
- sinal de interromper (CTRL+C no terminal; `SIGINT`)
- sinal de morte (já deu `kill -9 <PID>` em algum processo? `SIGKILL`)

Alguns sinais podem ser interceptados, outros não. `SIGKILL` e `SIGSTOP`, se não me engano, não são interceptáveis. <strike>Não me lembro se é possível enviar sinais de qualquer programa para qualquer programa, mas tenho certeza de que todo programa ancestral pode enviar um sinal para qualquer um de seus descendentes.</strike> Wtrmute mostra de modo excelente [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/214740/64969) como usar o envio de mensagens dentro da árvore de processos, de ancestral para descendente e vice-versa.

Tem uma [pergunta específica sobre sinais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/352539/64969)

### Via arquivo

> Resumo:
>   Plexidade? Half-duplex
>   Tipo de dado? Generalizado
>   Ativo/passivo? Passivo
>   Duração: Arbitrário

Escreve num arquivo, espera que outro processo leia. Porco e direto ao assunto. Se o arquivo for residente da RAM (RAM-FS), vai ser mais rápido.

Também poderia funcionar bem no caso de o SO demorar para fazer flush e permitir "leitura" do que estiver no cache de arquivos por outros processos, pode não ser tão ruim de performance.

A vantagem desse método é que a informação da comunicação fica persistida no caso de término abrupto do processo leitor.

### Via banco de dados

> Resumo:
>   Plexidade? Half-duplex
>   Tipo de dado? Generalizado
>   Ativo/passivo? Passivo
>   Duração: Arbitrário

Semelhante ao IPC por arquivo, mas o SGBD pode otimizar para a tabela ficar na RAM enquanto se realiza a escrita/leitura de maneira mais eficiente do que a leitura no cache do arquivo antes do flush.

### Arquivo de trava

> Resumo:
>   Plexidade? Uniplex
>   Tipo de dado? Booleano
>   Ativo/passivo? Passivo
>   Duração: Arbitrário

Lembrei-me desse tipo de comunicação ao escrever [essa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/242019/64969).

Em suma: quando você está em um ambiente multitarefa e precisa garantir a integridade de algum arquivo no sistema, não tendo nenhum servidor fixo para controlar essa situação, é criado um *arquivo de trava*.

O seguinte trecho exemplifica como funciona essa estratégia no ambiente `git`:

---

No caso, como não há servidor esperando ouvir uma mensagem, um processo `git` precisa decidir por si só, observando o ambiente (SO incluso como parte do ambiente) se ele pode realizar mudanças críticas ou não. Então, ele faz a seguinte chamada ao sistema operacional:

> SO, por favorzinho, cria para mim o arquivo `.git/index.lock`? Me retorna sucesso se é somente se eu fui quem conseguiu criar esse arquivo, ou se ele já existir me retorne falha

Para o qual, há duas respostas que o SO pode fornecer:

> Tá aqui, pequeno `git`, você criou o arquivo

Ou então, no caso de o arquivo já existir (ou que acabou de ser criado por outro processo em paralelo):

> Ô, animalzinho! Esse arquivo já existe!

Caso o arquivo exista previamente (e portanto ocorreu o erro), o `git` aborta graciosamente com essa mensagem que você foi recebido.

Caso o arquivo tenha sido criado (e portanto sucesso), o `git` segue feliz em seu processamento e, quando tiver terminado a atividade requerida, vai remover o arquivo de trava.

---

### Variável de ambiente

> Resumo:
>   Plexidade? Uniplex
>   Tipo de dado? Texto
>   Ativo/passivo? Passivo
>   Duração: Criação do processo filho

No shell-script, em diversos cantos precisamos fazer coisas assim:

```
export PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:$HOME/bin
./meu_script.sh
```

Isso é um jeito de passar para o programa `meu_scrpit.sh` a variável `$PATH`. Nota: se o `export` for omitido, o valor da variável alterado não será passado para o processo filho.

Essas variáveis só são passadas do processo pai para o processo filho, e se não me engano os valores são definidos na hora de fazer o `fork`.

### Código de retorno

> Resumo:
>   Plexidade? Uniplex
>   Tipo de dado? Byte
>   Ativo/passivo? Passivo
>   Duração: Término do processo filho

Quando um processo filho termina, ele pode notificar ao pai se deu tudo normal ou se deu alguma falha durante a execução. O padrão é retornar `0` quando não há erro (execução com sucesso) e com um código diferente de `0` quando há erro, sendo que cada valor corresponderia a um erro diferente.

Isso permite a um programa chamador tomar decisões de fluxo de execução condicionado ao sucesso ou fracasso do programa filho. O código de erro permite, também, informar ao programa chamador qual foi o problema encontrado (ou à pessoa que está executando na mão o programa).