# Erro: Unable to create 'C:/MyProject/.git/index.lock': File exists

Tags: git, commit

De repente fui "commitar" meu projeto, quando do nada apareceu essa mensagem:

> ```
> Erro: Unable to create 'C:/MyProject/.git/index.lock': File exists.
>
> If no other git process is currently running, this probably means a
> git process crashed in this repository earlier. Make sure no other git
> process is running and remove the file manually to continue.
> ```

Antes mesmo do commit, ao usar o comando `#git add .` já apareceu a mensagem. Não entendi o que pode ter acontecido. Quando exatamente isso ocorre? Como posso resolver esse problema?

Comment: Está dizendo que o arquivo existe. Navegue até o local e exclua-o.

Comment: Atomização da operação, assunto muito interessante! Vou escrever uma resposta sobre o assunto. Digo logo: isso se dá devido à concorrência de processos

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Um repositório `git` é um banco de dados de uso específico. Ele mantém *commits* (sua principal estrutura de dados), *branchs* (que contém nome e referência a um *commit*) e *tags* (contém as mesmas informações que um *branch*).

> A diferença entre *tag* e *branch* não está no escopo desta resposta

Existe uma estrutura semelhante a um *commit* especial chamado de *head*. Ela tem algumas operações:

- modificar conteúdo/elencar (como adição, remoção de arquivos, mudança de linhas, renomear arquivos)
- transformar em *commit*

A transformação em *commit* fará com que a estrutura tenha um SHA1 próprio de *commit*, tenha um *commit* pai, um autor e, também, movimentará o ponteiro do *branch* de trabalho. Após a transformação em *commit*, *head* estará com uma estrutura vazia.

Os comandos de elencar são, dentre outros:

- `add`
- `rm`
- `reset` ([primeira forma](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset))

O comando de transformar *head* em *commit* é:

- `commit`

Agora, estas operações elas são grandes, e portanto podem necessitar de um tempo grande para se concretizar. Imagina que você resolveu renomear um pacote Java de `br.com.acklay` para `plu.to.nio.marviana`, e que todos os outros fontes Java apontam para classes classes. Você precisaria elencar os 22936 arquivos fontes. Isso vai levar um tempo...

Então, inadvertidamente, você tenta commitar a mudança:

```
git commit -m 'decaimento radioativo do Cleidi'
```

Bem, se o sistema não tivesse algum jeito de identificar que o *head* estava sendo modificado, o *commit* gerado representaria um estado estranho e possivelmente corrompido dos dados, então é necessário haver alguma forma de [IPC](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/211430/64969) entre os dois processos.

No caso, a estratégia de IPC escolhida pelo `git` foi a criação atômica de um arquivo de trava. Essa estratégia é conhecida por *lockfile*.

> Mais tarde eu encontro o comando *nix que faz a criação atômica de um arquivo

No caso, como não há servidor esperando ouvir uma mensagem, um processo `git` precisa decidir por si só, observando o ambiente (SO incluso como parte do ambiente) se ele pode realizar mudanças críticas ou não. Então, ele faz a seguinte chamada ao sistema operacional:

> SO, por favorzinho, cria para mim o arquivo `.git/index.lock`? Me retorna sucesso se é somente se eu fui quem conseguiu criar esse arquivo, ou se ele já existir me retorne falha

Para o qual, há duas respostas que o SO pode fornecer:

> Tá aqui, pequeno `git`, você criou o arquivo

Ou então, no caso de o arquivo já existir (ou que acabou de ser criado por outro processo em paralelo):

> Ô, animalzinho! Esse arquivo já existe!

Caso o arquivo exista previamente (e portanto ocorreu o erro), o `git` aborta graciosamente com essa mensagem que você foi recebido.

Caso o arquivo tenha sido criado (e portanto sucesso), o `git` segue feliz em seu processamento e, quando tiver terminado a atividade requerida, vai remover o arquivo de trava.

---

## Quando essa mensagem aparece?

Em casos saudáveis, quando há alguma operação crítica em andamento por outro processo `git` em paralelo.

Em casos estranhos, o último processo `git` que requereu essa trava não conseguiu liberá-la (morreu prematuramente? Coitadinho...). Então o arquivo fica solto lá sem maiores propósitos. Talvez possa indicar alguma possível corrupção teórica do *head*, como também pode ser só um lixo esquecido.

## Como resolver?

Nos casos saudáveis, o ideal é esperar. E garantir que não haverá outro processo tentando travar o seu repositório enquanto isso. Se você usa o `SourceTree`, recomendo fortemente que você não abra sua janela, que a minimize ou mesmo a feche. O `SourceTree` só aciona um processo `git` quando está em primeiro plano, e muitas vezes espera alguma operação no usuário (nem que essa operação seja "dar foco na janela").

Nos casos estranhos, basta remover o arquivo `index.lock` e garantir que o repositório esteja saudável.

---

Durante um comando de `fetch`, precisei abortar o `git`. Quando tento rodar agora, ele mesmo diz o seguinte:

> If no other git process is currently running, this probably means a
>   git process crashed in this repository earlier. Make sure no other git
>   process is running and remove the file manually to continue.

Traduzindo:

> Se não tem nenhum outro processo git rodando agora, isso provavelmente significa que um processo git quebrou neste repositório mais cedo. Tenha certeza de que não há outro processo git rodando e remova manualmente o arquivo para continuar.

Então, na linha de comando, o `git` indica que se deve fazer o que está acima descrito.

Comment: Bom, aconteceu exatamente quando estava usando o Visual Code sincronizadamente usando git, ai fui abrir uma outra instancia do git usando o CMD. Mas legal, sua resposta está até interessante. heheh

Answer (score 2):

Execute o código abaixo e depois tente retomar o processo que queria fazer:

```
rm -f ./.git/index.lock
```

Comment: Obrigado. O companheiro acima acabou se empolgando e dissertou sobre o assunto!