# Git, Duvidas quando faço um commit

Tags: git, github

tenho uma duvida ao utilizar o git, e gostaria da ajuda de voces.

Tenho a seguinte situação:

- Estou desenvolvendo um novo recurso na minha aplicação, mas nao finalizei complementamente. Vamos supor que eu esteja desenvolvendo no pc em casa. Ai eu vou para o trabalho, e resolvo, na hora do almoço, dar continuidade no novo recurso.

Segue minha duvida... A aplicação fica no Github. Eu desenvolvi no pc de casa, e comitei inconpleto para terminar na hora do almoço no trabalho...

Qual a solução para não comitar coisas incompletas no git?

Desde já agradeço!

Comment: Normalmente você usa um processo de branches para evitar que coisas novas caiam em produção imediatamente, só aprovando posteriormente, após intensa revisão

Comment: Pode ajudar: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/80586/64969

Comment: Aqui eu falo sobre um ponto de vista não muito tradicional sobre o git: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/242019/64969

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cria um branch/ramo onde tens essa nova funcionalidade/feature. Quando ela estiver pronta faz merge com o `master`.

```
git checkout master
# criar novo ramo a partir do master
git checkout -b nova-ideia
```

E depois no trabalho:

```
git fetch origin # ou outro nome que deste ao repositório remoto
git checkout nova-ideia (sem o "-b" que é para criar novo)
```

Comment: O comando `git pull origin` também funcionaria?

Comment: @gato depende do que queres fazer. O git pull atualiza o ramo em que estás, faz merge. Se for para atualizar o que há no remote (em memória) o git fetch traz a informação fresca.

Comment: Valeu Sergio. Vou fazer uns testes aqui. Mas acho que é esse o caminho!

Comment: Tenho uma dúvida. O git checkout -b nova-ideia, vai criar um novo branch. Eu consigo subir as alteraçṍes desse novo branch para o servidor sem o commit? Minha arquitetura está assim: Pc de casa + Bitbucket + Pc do trabalho

Comment: @SamuelGomes tens de fazer commit para subir para o servidor. Mas no ramo `nova-ideia` podes apagar o commit e reescrever o histórico. Eu costumo enviar para o git e continuar noutro computador. Depois quando um pedaço está fixo faço commit permanente. Quando todo o ramo está pronto faço merge com o master.

Comment: @Sergio como eu apago o commit sem apagar o que foi feito? Mas de resto eu entendi. Valeu!

Comment: @SamuelGomes `git reset --soft HEAD^1` apaga o ultimo commit e deixa as mudanças no sitio. Depois se precisares de fazer o update do novo ramo podes fazer `git push -f origin` **mas atênção:** nunca faças isso no `master`! Certifica-te que estás no ramo certo :)

Comment: @Sergio você é mito. Obrigado!

Comment: @SamuelGomes fico contente de ajudar :)