# "Workspace is in use or cannot be created" após Eclipse fechar de modo inesperado

Tags: eclipse

Meu Eclipse fechou de modo inesperado. Ao tentar abrir novamente, ele mostra a seguinte mensagem:

[image: [Popup com o alerta "Workspace is in use or cannot be created"]]

Com os dizeres:

> The default workspace [...] is in use or cannot be created. Please choose a different one.

Em tradução livre:

> O ambiente de trabalho padrão [...] está em uso ou não pode ser criado. Favor escolha um outro.

Qual o procedimento para salvar meu workspace?

Estou usando Eclipse Oxygen, rodando com JDK 8u151. Windows 10

Comment: Poderia explicar o porquê do negativo para que eu possa melhorar a pergunta?

Answer (score 1):

O erro ocasionado foi devido a algo semelhante a o que o [@acklay](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/35406/acklay) passou com o Git: [Erro: Unable to create 'C:/MyProject/.git/index.lock': File exists](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/238885/64969)

No caso, o Eclipse criou dentro da pasta `$WORKSPACE/.metadata` um [arquivo de trava](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/214199/64969) chamado `.lock`:

[image: arquivo de trava <code>.lock</code> dentro do <code>$WORKSPACE/.metadata</code>]

Tentei remover o arquivo, mas...

[image: não é possível remover o arquivo]

Tentei encontrar o processo `eclipse.exe`, mas não encontrei no gerenciador de tarefas (tinha abortado de modo inesperado, afinal). Então, parti para a [solução indicada pelo @rray no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/40876125#40876125): reiniciar o computador.

Após reiniciar a máquina, o Eclipse abriu normalmente. Nem precisei apagar o arquivo de trava.