# Qual é a diferença entre socket e porta?

Tags: terminologia, socket, conexão, redes, arquitetura-computadores

Desenvolvendo um *app* orientado a serviços, me deparei com a seguinte questão: Qual é a diferença entre porta e *socket* dentro da estrutura computacional?

Comment: Você conecta um socket em uma porta? A porta pode estar aberta mas sem nenhum socket aberto nela?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/152457/4438007

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> O objetivo desta postagem é esclarecer a nomenclatura e prover uma metáfora para facilitar o entendimento. Para algo mais formalmente correto, veja [a resposta do @jsbueno](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/277762/64969)

Antes de mais nada, vamos analisar as palavras?

- *socket*

  Em Português, soquete. A palavra originou do inglês *socket* mesmo, que por sua vez veio do do francês antigo *soc*... no final, a origem significa "nariz de porco". Em questões de conexões elétricas, é a parte fêmea da conexão. [[1]](https://pt.wiktionary.org/wiki/soquete), [[2]](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/socket), [[3]](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/soc)

  [image: Soquete em formato de soc/nariz de porco]
- *porta*

  Ou *porto* em Português de Portugal. A palavra nesse uso veio da especificação em inglês, onde estava escrito *port*. Pelo que está descrito na origem da palavra no Wiktionary, vem do francês antigo *porte*/latim *porta*, no sentido de portão, passagem por onde coisas podem entrar. Também usado em alguns lugares como a parte fêmea de uma conexão (porta serial/ethernet, por exemplo). [[1] (etimologia 2)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/port), [[2]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_port_(hardware))

  [image: portas de computador]

Bem, ambos significam a parte fêmea de uma conexão, então isso acaba que não ajudou 100% a diferenciá-los.

Bem, então vamos para uma metáfora com tomadas?

Imagine que você tem a seguinte tomada suíça:

[image: tomada de 3 entradas, superior, esquerda inferior e direita inferior, padrão suíço]

Você tem 3 portas de entrada:

1. a superior
2. a esquerda inferior
3. a direita inferior

Se você tentar estabelecer uma conexão com uma dessas portas, você precisa de um cabo de plugue adequado para entrar na porta. Se o soquete estiver ligado na rede elétrica, então haverá uma corrente elétrica (haverá comunicação) entre o servidor de energia (sua casa, que é na Suíça para ter uma tomada dessas) e quem está consumindo a energia, o aparelho cliente.

Mas e se não tiver ligação no soquete? Então a porta é vacuosa. Você pode ligar o que for nela que não haverá comunicação.

A porta, então, é o identificador de onde quero me encaixar. O plugue é o meu padrão de conexão, definida no nível 4 (transporte) no modelo TCP/IP de redes. O *socket* seria a ligação dessa porta com a aplicação, que pode ser um servidor web, FTP, SSH ou qualquer outra aplicação (a aplicação aqui seria a rede elétrica).

---

### *Berkley sockets*

Como comentado na [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/277762/64969), senti falta dos sockets Unix. Mas acho de bom grado falar dos [sockets Berkley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets).

Esses tais sockets Berkley, na verdade, é uma API para se ter acesso a um ponto de comunicação. Ela prevê dois tipos de sockets comumente usados:

- socket de rede
- socket Unix

Ambos são pontos de conexão para se realizar [IPC](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/211430/64969) e são usados da mesma maneira: lê-se e escreve-se dados. A diferença entre os dois sockets é com quem a comunicação será feita. Sockets Unix são para conexões dentro do mesmo computador (como *pipes*), já sockets de rede são para computadores em rede.

Answer (score 10):

Socket é um recurso do sistema operacional que é conectado a uma porta. Uma porta é um número definido no protocolo de rede - em geral com 16 bits. Um socket é uma conexão em uma dada porta, e pertence sempre a um processo (programa). Já porta é um complemento do endereço de rede - no caso dos protocolos TCP e UDP, dentre outros, é como se o endereço de IP fosse o endereço do prédio, e a porta fosse o número do apartamento dentro do prédio.

Agora, só o "endereço completo" é só isso - o endereço. Para fazer uso dele, os programas de rede criam um socket que fica ligado a uma porta. Em termos concretos, um socket é uma estrutura de dados em memória, mantida pelo sistema operacional e um dos campos dessa estrutura é o "número da porta" ao qual ele está ligado. Em geral, os programas que atuam como servidores criam um socket que se liga a  um número fixo de porta que aceita uma conexão que chega naquele computador (a conexão chega em protocolo:ip:porta). Já programas clientes deixam o sistema operacional criar uma porta em um número "ao acaso" (há algumas regras) - e então eles tem uma conexão "saindo" do computador.

Uma porta só pode ter um socket associado a ela de cada vez. Quando um socket em modo "servidor" estiver aceitando conexões recebe uma conexão, o sistema operacional *cria* automaticamente um outro socket, usando uma porta aleatória, já conectado ao cliente, e retorna esse novo socket ao programa servidor. Ou seja, em todo o processo de comunicação, somente especificamos uma porta fixa: aquela que o servidor "escuta". Um cliente ao fazer uma conexão para um computador remoto, usa esse endereço de porta - e tanto no lado do cliente o sistema operacional cria um socket (no modo cliente) em uma porta qualquer, como no servidor, como parte do processo de estabelecer a conexão, o sistema operacional faz o mesmo: cria um socket numa porta qualquer. Dessa forma o programa servidor fica livre para, usando várias estratégias, poder continuar "ouvindo" novas conexões que cheguem na porta original.

Nos comentários aparecem as questões complementares -

> Você conecta um socket em uma porta? A porta pode estar aberta mas sem
>   nenhum socket aberto nela?

Eu usei o termo "associar" um socket a uma porta. O termo técnico usado no sistema operacional é "bind" - não sei se tem uma tradução oficial possivelmente sim - poderia ser "vinculado" . 
Quanto a "porta estar aberta": a porta é apenas um número de endereço.  Se não houver um socket associado, é como se não houvesse nada lá. No entanto faz sentido falar de portas "abertas" e "fechadas" no firewall - que é outra camada do sistema. Na prática uma porta "fechada" no firewall faz com que todas as conexões entrantes naquela porta sejam descartadas antes de chegarem ao socket.

Abaixo, eu mostro num terminal Linux a saída do comando `lsof` que mostra quais conexões ativas (sockets) um programa tem - como alvo do comando, uso um processo de servidor web (a linguagem Python tem um servidor simples de exemplo embutido, que é iniciado pelo primeiro comando).

Eu uso o lsof para localizar o número do processo ouvindo a porta 8080,
em seguida repito o comando pelo número do processo, e faço o mesmo depois de iniciar uma conexão cliente para o servidor (com o comando telnet) - e então é possível ver o socket criado pelo S.O. para essa conexão:

```
[gwidion@village]$ python3 -m http.server 8080
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8080 (http://0.0.0.0:8080/) ...
^Z
[2]+  Stopped                 python3 -m http.server 8080
[gwidion@village]$ bg
[2]+ python3 -m http.server 8080 &
[gwidion@village]$ lsof -i4:8080
COMMAND   PID    USER   FD   TYPE   DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
python3 18085 gwidion    3u  IPv4 11260544      0t0  TCP *:webcache (LISTEN)
[gwidion@village]$ lsof -p 18085|grep -i tcp
python3 18085 gwidion    3u  IPv4 11260544       0t0     TCP *:webcache (LISTEN)
[gwidion@village]$ telnet localhost 8080
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
^]
telnet> ^Z
[3]+  Stopped                 telnet localhost 8080
[gwidion@village]$ bg
[3]+ telnet localhost 8080 &
[gwidion@village]$ lsof -p 18085|grep -i tcp
python3 18085 gwidion    3u  IPv4 11260544       0t0     TCP *:webcache (LISTEN)
python3 18085 gwidion    4u  IPv4 11251437       0t0     TCP localhost:webcache->localhost:48976 (ESTABLISHED)
```

(Note que o lsof chama a porta 8080 de "webcache" por que é normalmente associada com um serviço com esse nome)

Comment: Acho que não contempla o Unix socket, para IPC na mesma máquina. (PS: modelo Berkley de socket, não necessariamente entendimento universal)

Comment: Não entendi o negativo, poderia explicar?

Comment: @dvd eu não achei encheção de linguiça. Achei muito bem estruturado, muito melhor do que as que eu costumo escrever, inclusive. Gostei da estrutura, apresentando a resposta logo nas primeiras duas frases do primeiro parágrafo, então concluindo com mais profundidade até o terceiro, para então partir para exemplos concretos. Mas essa é a minha percepção, eu advogo a favor desta resposta. Você foi assertivo no seu ponto, então creio que podemos apenas concordar em discordar sobre a qualidade desta resposta ;-)

Comment: " e aí vem um monte de termos técnicos sem explicações claras " Quais exatamente são os "termos técnicos sem explicações claras" nessa resposta?

Comment: @jsbueno, tentei elaborar uma metáfora sobre portas e sockets. Não vejo como poderia escrever melhor sobre socket propriamente dito, então apono para esta sua resposta. Como senti falta dos sockets Unix, dei uma pincelada sobre eles na minha resposta