# Dificuldade em C: ler duas funções ao mesmo tempo[Concluido]

Tags: c

Gostaria de saber como executar duas funções ao mesmo tempo em c
Sendo uma o while e a outra um scanf:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <windows.h> //para usar o sleep

int main(){
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");
    char name[10];
    int sec=0,chose,monster=64,Fome=10,Higiene=10,Felicidade=10,i=0;

printf("Insira o Nome do Monstrinho.\n");
scanf("%s",name);

system("cls"); // Limpar a tela

while(i<80000){
system("cls");//limpa a tela windows    
printf("###########################################\n");
printf("#Nome: %s                                 #\n",name);
printf("#Tempo de Vida : %ds                      #\n",sec);
printf("#Fome:%d   Felicidade;%d  Higiene:%d      #\n",Fome,Felicidade,Higiene); 
printf("#                                         #\n"); 
printf("#                                         #\n");
printf("###########################################\n");
printf("(1)Comida (2)Carinho (3)Banho (4)...\n");
Sleep(1000); //função sleep
sec++; //segundos
}
```

Seria antes ou depois da { (chave de while), e como posso implementar.

```
    printf("Digite uma opção:\n");
    scanf("%d",chose); //variavel de escolha de ação
}
```

Comment: Você realmente precisa fazer isso? Saiba que, neste caso, você estará trabalhando com processamento paralelo. Dentro dos modelos de processamento paralelo que existem, não sei qual o mais adequado para um jogo CLI (estou considerando o seu tamagoshi um jogo, a propósito), mas eu sou tendencioso a um modelo de variáveis compartilhadas (vide minha resposta sobre [IPC](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/214199/64969)).

Comment: Sim, é preciso fazer isso

Comment: Talvez tenha uma solução melhor, dê mais informações sobre o que está fazendo e porque precisa disto, está tendo algum problema no momento?

Comment: Boa noite, então o trabalho e realizar um menu que atualiza com os segundos(sec) utilizando a função sleep, porém não encontrei um meio de funcionar também o scanf junto.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Uma possível solução seria:

```
// todo código anterior
    printf("(1)Comida (2)Carinho (3)Banho (4)...\n");

    printf("Digite uma opção:\n");
    scanf("%d",chose); //variavel de escolha de ação

    Sleep(1000); //função sleep
    sec++; //segundos
}
```

O que ele vai fazer de fato: Dentro do teu loop `while` ele vai pedir para digitar uma opção a cada iteração do loop, esperar 1 segundo e então dar seguimento ao código, perceba que o tempo de espera para a entrada não conta, ou seja, o usuário pode levar 5 minutos para resolver escolher uma das opções e ainda assim após escolher ele ira esperar 1 segundo para concluir, isto porque tu definiu os 1000 milissegundos (1 segundo dividido por mil) de pausa.

Logo após o usuário escolher a opção, tu vai precisar colocar um controle de fluxo como um `if` para cada uma das opções, eu te recomendo usar o fluxo `switch - case` ele é mais adequado que o `if` para estes casos onde uma variável pode assumir diferentes valores, além de ser ser mais legível e deixar o código mais elegante, tudo isto deve ficar dentro do teu loop `while`, perceba que o teu loop é o controle de fluxo da tua aplicação, então todas as ações ficarão dentro dele para que se mantenha o ciclo.

Comment: Ainda não está funcionando

Comment: @RaulLima, qual o problema que apresenta?

Comment: não atualiza a variável sec (segundos) no while.

Comment: @RaulLima, mas perceba que tu não usa ela no `while`, veja que este é chamado de "loop infinito" ou seja, tu passa uma condição verdadeira (true) e ele nunca irá sair desse loop, tu inicia a variável `i` com `0` e teu loop diz o seguinte: "enquanto `i` for menor que `80000`", porém o valor de `i` nunca é atualizado, ou seja, ele sempre será menor que `80000`, isso equivale a um `while(true)`.

Comment: Já a variável `sec`inicia com `0` e esta incrementando no fim do loop, ou seja, no próximo ciclo o valor irá mudar.

Comment: Legal o pessoal negativar sem explicar o motivo ou sem apresentar uma solução mais adequada. (y)

Comment: @bruno101: sua solução não atende ao solicitado ao autor da pergunta, ela executa os comandos sequencialmente enquanto a pergunta pede para que as execuções ocorram ao mesmo tempo ou seja: em paralelo. Veja os comentários de Jefferson Quesado  e Maniero na pergunta.

Comment: @anonimo, eu apresentei a resposta para o que ele queria e fiz recomendações fora da pergunta, inclusive em comentários, caso não resolvesse bastaria não aprovar a resposta e ai sim entenderia as negativas, agora negativar sem motivo ou porque não gostou  apenas, ai foge o escopo.

Comment: Então o problema não foi resolvido. porém não dei negativar

Comment: Então @RaulLima, eu te perguntei o que esta acontecendo, qual ocomportamento do teu programa para entender exatamente onde não esta funcionando para te ajudar.

Comment: o trabalho é realizar um menu que atualiza com os segundos(sec) utilizando a função sleep, porém não encontrei um meio de funcionar também o scanf junto.Problema, o scanf na lê dentro do loop, gostaria de saber se tem alguma maneira de que o loop continue junto com o scanf ou separados, pois dentro dele,o loop só continua com a digitação de qualquer numero, quebrando a proposta de atualização de tela

Comment: @RaulLima, agora sim ficou claro o que tu quer fazer, pois bem, para fazer isso será um pouco mais complicado, pois tu precisa usar `threads`, atualmente teu projeto segue uma lógica processual, ou seja, um passo depois do outro, uma instrução necessita esperar a outra terminar para então ser executada, não é que a minha resposta esteja errada, ela funciona, porém não é adequada ao que tu precisa. Usando `threads` tu consegue fazer com que duas ou mais funções sejam executadas simultaneamente, então tu vai isolar o contador de segundos em uma `thread` e o teu loop em outra.

Comment: @RaulLima, aqui nós esbarramos em alguns possíveis problemas, até onde eu sei, nenhuma implementação de compilador `C` para windows tem suporte a `threads` fazendo com que seja necessário alguma lib externa, não sei precisar em qual versão do `gcc` foi implementada de forma nativa, porém se tu estiver usando uma implementação anterior, terá o mesmo problema que no windows, além do mais, o uso de `threads` é extremamente desencorajado no `C` e no `C++`, pois as chances de problemas como segmentação de memória são bem grandes.

Comment: consegue cara seguir seu primeiro conselho, implementando um pouco mais, até no momento problema resolvido