# Como parar um session?

Tags: java, hibernate, session, thread

Estou trabalhando com Java Swing. Tenho uma tela de relatório, que quando é clicado no botão confirmar, ele chama o método gerar. O método gerar vai na controle, e a controle vai na dão para buscar do banco os dados para preencher o relatório... Até aí tudo ok...

Porém a tarefa que estou trabalhando é justamente interromper todo esse processo. Ex: Quando clica em gerar o relatório, uma telinha de aguarde aparece. Vamos considerar que está demorando muito os selects do banco, e o usuário queira cancelar, e voltar a utilizar a aplicação novamente (sem precisar finalizar o sistema). Ou seja, ele vai clicar no botão cancelar da telinha de aguarde, e ele vai finalizar todos os processos

Qual solução posso usar?

Uso hibernate, preciso fazer meu sistema entender que AONDE E O QUE ele estiver fazendo, após ele clicar em cancelar, ele tem que parar TUDO. E liberar minha aplicação pra uso

Comment: Presumo que você esteja utilizando uma nova thread para gerar o relatório, neste caso, pare a thread. Caso necessário, você pode colocar um timeout.
Mais inormações de como parar uma thread, pode ver aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/45320/como-parar-uma-thread

Comment: @FilipeL.Constante Filipe, coloquei abaixo um exemplo de como está meu código.. não estou usando threads..

Comment: Edite a sua pergunta e coloque na pergunta o código por gentileza.

Comment: Sugiro que use uma thread p/ gerar o relatório, caso contrário sua aplicação ficará em espera até que o relatório seja concluído.